# SublimeHaskell cannot build

Tags: haskell, build, sublimetext3

I am using Sublime Text 3 on mac el capitan, and when I try to build a haskell file, I receive the following error message:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'runhaskell'
[cmd: ['runhaskell', 'path_to_my_file']]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
[Finished]
```

The SublimeHaskell User settings is as follows:

```
{
    "add_to_PATH":
    [
        "/Users/durand/Library/Haskell/bin/",
        "/usr/local/bin/"
    ],
    "enable_ghc_mod": false,
    "enable_hdevtools": false,
    "enable_hsdev": false,
}
```

I don't know why the path in error message does not include the path I specified in the User setting, and am not sure if this causes the problem. But using SublimeHaskellREPL: ghci currentfile works fine.
Also, the `runhaskell` is located in `/usr/local/bin/` but for some reason I cannot make this directory seen by SublimeHaskell. In addition, both the `echo "$PATH"` and `/etc/paths` tell me that the `/usr/local/bin/` is in the path variable, which confuses me even further.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: don't know how or if you can fix this inside sublime but you should be fine if you add it to your `$PATH` environment (see for example http://architectryan.com/2012/10/02/add-to-the-path-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/#.V5CMFriLS8E)

Comment: Now my `/etc/paths` file is `/usr/local/bin`
`/usr/bin`
`/bin`
`/usr/sbin`
`/sbin`
`/Users/durand/Library/Haskell/bin/` but the error message I get is exactly the same. I am quite confused then.

Comment: you probably have to restart sublime or even the computer

Comment: I restarted the computer, and it worked; then I turned off the computer and went for dinner. After returning, I turned on the computer and it failed again, with the same error message... Now I have completely no idea of what is going on... Thanks for the advice, which at least achieved one success!

Comment: As a side-issue, I ended up starting to use vim for text editing. :P